# There is some way to guarantee an unique (not pooled) database connection per user session in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, connection-pooling

Due to locking concerns, we need to guarantee that every asp.net session get it's own connection in the connection pool. One connection per session, not shared by any other connection.

Any ideas?

There is no RIGHT answer, we are just out of ideas and need some suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it truly need to be "per session"?  Or is it sufficient for them to keep the same connection through a given page request, but not necessarily the same connection on subsequent requests?  Maintaining a single connection throughout a user session sounds risky - that's a LOT of open connections (depending on how many users), each one lasting a very long time (depending on session timeouts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is SQL Server, in the database connection string add Pooling='false' and then connections will not pooled.

In general connection pooling is good for your application.  Open, do something, close and dispose of the connection back to the pool.  I've had instances where the connections were not being disposed of properly which caused issues.

Make sure all connections are in a using block (which will call dispose automatically) or if they are in a try catch, make sure in finally dispose is called on the connection.

Other than that, if pooling is not desired, alter the connection string not to use the pool.